# How to change canvas image on click?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onclick

I am trying to change the image of canvas on click according to count of click being even or odd.
 Basically i want to make a zero and cross game in which image on canvas changes to a cross or zero depending upon the count of mouse click.How to track count of click on canvas? Please help.
Please guide me as i am a beginner in html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title> samp1 </title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid   #000000;">
</canvas>
<style>
#mycanvas {
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:10px;
}
</style>
<img src="http://images.all-free- download.com/images/graphicthumb/roses_554954.jpg" id="my" width="200"  height="100"/>
<img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/flower_lighting_554944.jpg" id="ny" width="200" height="100"/>
<script>
var i=0;
function fn(){
if(i%2==0)
ctx.drawImage(im,0,0,can.width,can.height);
else
ctx.drawImage(in,0,0,can.width,can.height);
i++;}
var can = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
       var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
var im=document.getElementById("my");
var in=document.getElementById("ny");
can.addEventListener("click", fn, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe if you give the images the same class. And use .toggle() to switch between the images. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @rahul is your example related to your issue? I think it's still far from what you say in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 very small errors:

- 'in' is a reserved word in javascript.
- you have a space in the URL for the 'my' img element

With those corrected your codes should work the way you want.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/w09tyftt/1/

```
<style>
    #mycanvas {
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-left:10px;
    }
</style>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid   #000000;">
<img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/roses_554954.jpg" id="my" width="200" height="100" />
<img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/flower_lighting_554944.jpg" id="ny" width="200" height="100" />
<script>
    var i = 0;

    function fn() {
        if (i % 2 == 0) ctx.drawImage(im, 0, 0, can.width, can.height);
        else ctx.drawImage(vin, 0, 0, can.width, can.height);
        i++;
    }
    var can = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    var im = document.getElementById("my");
    var vin = document.getElementById("ny");
    can.addEventListener("click", fn, false);
</script>
```